# Steam game starts, syncs and stops

Tags: games, steam, 19.10

So I have just recently downloaded Steam Play or Proton and tried to play FF9. When clicking play it simply starts, syncs and stops, no window is opening.

Comment: If you mean **Final Fantasy 9**, here's info from the ProtonDB website: https://www.protondb.com/app/377840

Comment: Went to the site you mentions ajgringo619 but I'm unsure how to use the advice given...

Comment: I don't own that game so I have no way to test any of the suggestions. When you open Steam, go to the FF9 forum and ask there.

Answer (score 0):

So unsure if this counts as an answer but I just play by opening up steam and starting the .exe file from the browse local files option under game management. So I guess the issue is the launcher but I don't know how to fix it.